RegEx to replace \[ ... \] with $$ ... $$
In a Markdown string, I would like to replace the equation delimiters \[ ... \] and \( ... \) with $$ ... $$ and $ ... $ respectively in JavaScript.
I wrote the following RegEx:
// Replace \[ ... \] with $$ ... $$
let output = string.replace(/\\\[(.*?)\\\]/gs, function (outer, inner) {
  return `$$ ${inner} $$`;
})

// Replace \( ... \) with $ ... $
output = output.replace(/\\\((.*?)\\\)/g, function (outer, inner) {
  return `$ ${inner} $`;
});

It works fine, but sometimes, the delimiters are not on the same line as on this example:
\[
-2x - 1 + 2x - 1 = -2
\]

In this particular case, the delimiters are not replaced. Here is the expected output:
$$ -2x - 1 + 2x - 1 = -2 $$

I can't figure out how to modify my regular expression to get this expected answer.

The problem does not come from the regular expression. Your RegEx is OK. You have to trim ${inner} before returning the function.
@CherryDT, can you remove the duplicate tag ? I would like to post the full answer.

@CherryDT OP uses s dotall flag which is supposed to work since the release of ECMA 2018. I reopened the post since dot not matching newline is oviously not the cause.

Whoever upvoted the very first comment must also be unaware of the s flag's effect on .

Indeed. Perhaps the syntax highlighting here should be updated, right now g is yellow but the s afterwards is white.

Can't reproduce. The only issue I see compared to the "desired output" is that the inner part is not trimmed of the newlines like Fifi said above, but the described problem of the replacing itself not happening does not occur.

Your regex was also capturing newlines in the capture group. So I have involved \s* to be excluded from the capture group. You may also use \n* instead of \s*.
Demo


const str1 = `\\[ ... \\]`
const str2=`\\( ... \\)`
const str3=`\\[
-2x - 1 + 2x - 1 = -2
\\]`

let output = str1.replace(/\\\[\s*([^\n]*?)\s*\\\]/gms, function (outer, inner) {
  return `$$ ${inner} $$`;
})
console.log(output);


output = str2.replace(/\\\(\s*([^\n]*?)\s*\\\)/gms, function (outer, inner) {
  return `$$ ${inner} $$`;
});
console.log(output);

output = str3.replace(/\\\[\s*([^\n]*?)\s*\\\]/gms, function (outer, inner) {
  return `$$ ${inner} $$`;
})
console.log(output);



